# $(document).ready(function() is not working after page refresh in ie6

Tags: jquery, jquery-post

$(document).ready(function() not working after page refresh in ie 6.Is there any problem to use?Whether it will work in all condition when page load happens...In other browser also?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a JavaScript error somewhere on the page? One of these will stop any JavaScript from executing

You can test this by using firebug on firefox or Chrome ships with a console for developers now. Found a link that [explains some basic checks](http://www.cmsmarket.com/resources/dev-corner/92-how-to-check-for-javascript-errors) you can do with IE also

Comment: no...whether $(document).ready(function(){} will work all time,all browser when page happens......